# How to update menuitems from the menu manager?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have 2 components which should not depend upon each other but it should contribute to same menu.

I want a Context menu called "ABC" and it should contain 2 sub menu say "XYZ" and "PQR".

First component creating "XYZ"
and Second componet creating "PQR" then it should come under "ABC"

In my implemented code it is showing 2 "ABC" menu.

Please help me.

code snippet:

1st component

```
MenuManager showInSubMenu = new MenuManager("ABC");
showInSubMenu.add("XYZ");
menu.appendToGroup("group.open", showInSubMenu);
```

2nd component

```
MenuManager showInSubMenu = new MenuManager("ABC");
showInSubMenu.add("PQR");
menu.appendToGroup("group.open", showInSubMenu);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your requirements and your design idea do not match up.

If those two components need to work **on the same** menu then they **must** have some sort of dependency.

I am *guessing* that your problem is that those two components should be working with the **same** MenuManager instance. You see, your code is creating **two** menu managers; and adding information into that; and then you are surprised that your menus show up *twice*?

In that sense: the only solution I see is: step back, and figure those parts that your two components both need to talk to. Then create that new component C (which represents those common parts); and then your other two existing components have to work with that new C thingy.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: You are very welcome; I hope it helps. If so ... and nothing else comes in, please consider accepting the answer sooner or later.